# Question regarding a while loop and how to re ask a y/n question

Tags: java, while-loop

I am creating code that translated a word (obtained by the user) into Pig Latin. My code is working really good, except for one thing. I want the user to type in "y" or "n" to determine if the code will be run or not. I am using a while loop to determine what to execute. If a user types anything but the two listed above, I want it to ask again. At the moment I have a placeholder that calls the user silly and to restart the code. How can I accomplish this? Thanks a ton everyone!

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String playGame;
    String word;

    // Explains what the program does \\
    System.out.println("Welcome to Coulter's Pig Latin Translator!");
    System.out.println("If you choose to play, you will be asked to type a word which will be translated.");
    System.out.println();

    // Asks the user if they would like to play and checks 'y' or 'n' using a while statement \\
    System.out.println("Would you like to play? [y/n]: ");
    playGame = stdIn.next();

    while(playGame.equals("y") || playGame.equals("n")) // While expression that will check if the user enters a 'y' or 'n'
    {
        if (playGame.equals("y")) // Executes if the user entered 'y'
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter the word that you would like to translate: ");
            word = stdIn.next(); // Receives the word the user wishes to translate

            System.out.println("_______________________________________________________");

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("You entered the word: " + word); // Displays what the user entered

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Translation: " + solve(word)); // Displays the solved word

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Thanks for playing!"); // 
            return; // Ends the code

        }

        else if(playGame.contentEquals("n")) // Executes if the user entered 'n'
        {
            System.out.println("That's okay! Come back when you want to.");
            return; // Ends the code
        }   
    }

    System.out.println("_______________________________________________________");
    System.out.println("Don't be silly. Restart and type either 'y' or 'n'"); // Tells the user to restart if they entered anything but 'y' or 'n'

}

// Word translator code using a new static\\
public static String solve (String word) 
{
    String temp = word.toLowerCase();
    char[] vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}; // Stores vowels in an array
    char first = temp.charAt(0); // Defines first character for later use

    for (int i = 0; i < vowels.length; i++) // Looks for first vowel to replace it
    {
        if (first == vowels[i]) 
        {
            return word + "way"; // Replaces checked vowel
        }
    }

    word = word.substring(1); // Returns the string to the end of the word
    word += first + "ay";


    return word; // Returns the translated word to the program above
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are asking for the input here:

```
playGame = stdIn.next();
```

That simply has to go into your loop then:

```
playOn = true;
while(playOn) {
  playGame = stdIn.next();
  if ( y ) { ... play 
  } else {
    if ( n ) { ... dont play, set playOn = false
    } else {
      ... ask again
    } 
  }
```

The above is just meant as inspiration, and to point: what really matters here is that you get your if/else chain, and the corresponding "blocks" right. You need another if/else completely within the first "else" block!

Answer (score 1):

Since the part of your code that you want to be repeated is only the initial question, that is all that should be in the loop:

```
boolean askAgain = true;
while(askAgain) {
    // print your prompt;
    playGame = stdIn.next();
    if (playGame.equals("y") || playGame.equals("n")) {
        askAgain = false;
    }
}

// Now do your if/elseif for which letter was retrieved.
```

It's good practice to only loop over parts of your code that may actually be repeated.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to have your `playGame = stdIn.next();` line and prompt to run at the start of the while loop instead of just before it. Then you can check if it is `y`, `n` or something else just after that.